# How to get the slidetype (type-attribute) of a slidelayout-slide?

Tags: c#, vsto, powerpoint

Application is a C# based VSTO-AddIn for PowerPoint.

Each SlideLayout in powerpoint has a type. Is there way to get the type in an VSTO-AddIn? Up to now I just know how to get it from the SlideLayout.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the PowerPoint object model exposes an enumeration `PpSlideLayout` so something like

```
PowerPoint.PpSlideLayout theLayout = theSlide.Layout;
```

Here's a code snippet that creates a new slide (which requires assigning a CustomLayout), shows the string values of the custom layout and the PpSlideLayout, then assigns a different PpSlideLayout

```
PowerPoint.Presentation p = this.Application.ActivePresentation; 
PowerPoint.PpSlideLayout layoutBlank = PowerPoint.PpSlideLayout.ppLayoutBlank;
PowerPoint.CustomLayout custLayout = p.SlideMaster.CustomLayouts[1];
PowerPoint.Slide s = p.Slides.AddSlide(2, custLayout);
System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(s.CustomLayout.Name + ", " + s.Layout.ToString());
s.Layout = layoutBlank;
```